# Date Column coming as null while import using maatwebsite

Tags: php, laravel-6, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

Tried to import excel using laravel maatwebsite. Date column getting as null.

Actual column header is Date. I tried renaming it to some random name and then imported it, it works. Following formatting options tried :

- number[general]
- text
- date

maatwebsite/excel version is "^3.1"
laravel version is 6.20.41

Excel File :

[Sample Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB6lc.png)

Code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports\Master;

use App\Models\Master\RiscoveryInsuranceSettlement;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsFailures;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnFailure;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date;
use DB, Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;
use Carbon\Carbon;


class RiscoverySettlementImport implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow
{
    use Importable,SkipsFailures;


    /**
     * Merge excel date and time
     * @param $date
     * @param $time
     * @return static
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->startRow = 1;
    }

    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        dd($row);
    }
   }
```

Result

```
array:37 [
  "insurance_company" => "Aditya Birla Insurance"
  "policy_number" => "RISVRY00287267"
  "carrier_policy_no" => "GHI-AIRPAY-000002"
  "date" => null
  "month" => 44593
  "name_of_product" => "Group Health Care"
  "type" => "Group Health Care"
  "total_premium" => 5963
  "without_gst_amount" => 5053.3898305085
  "ncb_amount" => null
  "od_premium" => 0
  "tp_premium" => 0
  "irda_od" => 0
  "irda_tp" => 0
  "irda_commission" => 0
  "irda_commission_amount" => 0
  "irda_tp_amount" => 0
  "irda_od_amount" => 0
  "umbo_od_tp_commission" => 0
  "excess_digital_enablement" => null
  "irda_excess" => 0
  "irda_excess_amount" => 0
  "name_of_partner" => "AIRPAY"
  "payout" => 0.38
  "partner_payout_od" => 0
  "partner_payout_tp" => 0
  "payout_amount" => 1920.2881355932
  "payment_reference" => "8e98172033bb33d48deabce6"
  "insurance_co_booking_status" => null
  "status_billedunbilled" => null
  "invoice_number" => null
  "invoice_amount" => null
  "receipt_date" => null
  "partner_paid_status" => null
  "vendor" => null
  "amount" => null
  "comments" => null
]
```

Comment: Try  to print with $row[3]. Is it returning any value ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert those data to db then you have to create a model to import data. I think you know well how to create a model after that in your import class remove **WithHeadingRow** because you are not import data by column heading anymore.

From

```
class RiscoverySettlementImport implements ToModel,WithHeadingRow
```

To

```
class RiscoverySettlementImport implements ToModel
```

```
public function model(array $row)
    {
         return new model_name([
            'col_1' => $row[0], // col_1 will come from your model
            'col_2' => $row[1], // col_2 will come from your model
            'col_3' => $row[2], // col_3 will come from your model
             ... Add all columns
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: can you please explain me how to implement this?

Comment: I have updated the code